# socket.io client can't callback(wait for response) to nodejs sever

Tags: python, node.js, socket.io

I tried to make the server to wait for response from client(web app) that take 'fall' event call form server. But it wouldn't wait. Also the server will have to received 'fall' event from another client(fall detection:python) then that client have to wait for response from the server, but now it(fall detection) will call out fall event all the time when it detected fall.

```
//Client code
socket.on('fall', (data, callback) => {        
        if (confirm("fall detect " + data)) {            
            alarmSound.play();//function to play sound
            setTimeout(function() {}, 5000);            
        }
        callback({
            "response" : "ok",
        });
    });
```

```
//Nodejs Server code
const socketio = require('socket.io');
const io = socketio(server);
io.on("connection", function(socket) {
    console.log("New user connected.", socket);

    socket.on('Fall', (data, callback) => {
        const rpiID = data.rpiID;
        console.log("Fall detected at Cam ", rpiID);
        io.emit('fall', rpiID, function (cdata) {
            while(!cdata);
        });
        // socket.emit('image', { image: true, buffer: buf.toString('base64') });
        callback({
            status: "ok",
        });
    });
```

```
#socketio loop test code(python)
import socketio
sio = socketio.Client()
host = 'http://localhost:8080'
rpiID = '3'

while True:
    sio.connect(host)
    @sio.event
    def connect():
        print("Connected to", host)
        
    @sio.event
    def connect_error():
        print("Connection failed")    

    @sio.event
    def disconnect():
        print("Disconnected from", host)      
    
    print('My sio id :', sio.sid)
    sio.emit('Fall', {'rpiID' : rpiID})
    sio.disconnect();
```

Comment: Is your python code giving an error? Possibly on line 1?

Comment: No it sent normally i just test if loop sent socket.io to server and try to make server wait for response from client.

Comment: Just so you know `setTimeout(function() {}, 5000);` does nothing.  That just schedules a non-blocking timeout with a null callback.  It accomplishes nothing.  Your other code continues to run and when this timer fires, it calls the callback that does nothing.  It doesn't pause your code for 5 seconds - it's non-blocking and asynchronous.

Comment: Also, remove the `while(!cdata)`.  It's unclear what that's trying to do, but it won't accomplish anything useful either.  It appears like you would benefit from some serious reading about how the single-threaded and event-driven system in nodejs works.  You can't block or loop waiting for some condition because that blocks the event loop so nothing can happen except your loop and the loop condition can neve become true.